# How do I copy a DB dump file to a remote computer?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, pg-restore

I want to create a copy of my database from one server to another (my laptop to a server for example). Ive been looking online about how to do it and found this article:http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-copy-database/ However I am confused when it says

> "Second, copy the dump file to the remote server"

I know how to `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` but now sure what they mean by copy the dump file?

Comment: They mean: Copying a file from one computer to the other. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows and are using RDP to connect to the server you can just select the dump file, press CTRL-C, switch to the server connection and browse to a folder where you would like to copy the file to and press CTRL-V.

If your laptop and the server are on the same network, you can create a file share on either your laptop or on the server (or use an existing one) and use Windows Explorer to copy-paste the files over.

There is also a [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) command if you want to do it from a DOS box or batch file.

If you are using Linux, again, it depends on how you can connect to your server. There are options to mount a remote file share using NFS or Samba and copy files over, or you can use `scp` to copy files over an SSH connection.

This way you can have a "copy" of the dump file on the remote server, and use `pg_restore` to restore that copy of the dump file.